# mysql order by closest date/hour before or after

Tags: mysql, date

I have a mysql table that has a column that stores dates but isn't in the date format, it's a varchar.

The column is called `data_hora` and have dates in the `dd/mm/yy` format, example: `06/09/2012 15:00`, so I had to convert to date format in mysql query.

And I need to get the closest date and hour before or after the current time, I came up with the following code, but for some reason it seems to get only closest date but not hour, weird?!?!

```
SELECT str_to_date(data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_hora 
FROM requisicoes 
ORDER BY abs(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') - data_hora) LIMIT 1
```

**Help :(**

Comment: don't forget to include time condition in where clause to improve performance: `where data_hora between DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR) and DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)`

Comment: @danihp: a full table scan and conversion of each string to a timestamp will still be required.  The sort & limit will be just as effective; performing a filter will actually only add extra overhead in this case.

Comment: @eggyal, sure! I figured that data_hora was a time field...but not!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

Your ORDER BY Clause has to be changed

```
SELECT str_to_date(data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i') AS data_hora 
FROM requisicoes 
ORDER BY abs(TIMEDIFF( NOW() , str_to_date(data_hora, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i'))) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `TIMEDIFF` returns a `TIME` value, which is limited to the range `'-838:59:59'` to `'838:59:59'`: this may or may not be sufficient for the OP's needs.  Whilst not linear in respect of a time argument, the result of `ABS()` is indeed a strictly increasing integer so it does work -- but I don't think it's a great hack to rely upon.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't format `NOW()` to a string: it is already a `TIMESTAMP` value; instead, take the (absolute) difference between the present [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) and that of the `data_hora` alias for your selected `STR_TO_DATE()` column:

```
ORDER BY ABS(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(data_hora))
```

If at all possible, I would advise altering your schema so that your `data_hora` column is stored as a `TIMESTAMP`: it will greatly improve the performance of queries of this sort.